# Import array of image as thumbnail in ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs

i'm trying to display an array with some infos and images. I tried using map, and everything works just fine, until i try to place the image. What i'm doing wrong?

This is my portfolio.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import "../sass/Portfolio.scss";
    import { PortfolioList } from "./data/PortfolioList";

    let portfolio = PortfolioList.map((portfolio, key) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-6 portfolio-item" key={key}>
          <img src={portfolio.image} alt="Imagem do Portfolio" />
          <figcaption className="portfolio-info">
            <h1 className="portfolio-heading">{portfolio.description}</h1>
            <a href={portfolio.button} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              Visitar
            </a>
          </figcaption>
        </div>
      );
    });

    const Portfolio = () => {
      return (
        <section id="portfolio">
          <div className="separator" />
          <div className="container">
            <h1 className="heading-sobre">Alguns dos meus trabalhos</h1>
            <div className="row">{portfolio}</div>
          </div>
        </section>
      );
    };

export default Portfolio;
```

Then, i created a PortfolioList with my array

```
import barberclube from "../../img/sites/barber-clube85.png";
export const PortfolioList = [
  {
    image: { barberclube },
    description: "Website em Wordpress para uma barbearia",
    button: "https://barbearia.clube85.com"
  },
  {
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/380x250",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor amet sic culture and community sports competition.",
    button: "https://google.com"
  }
];
```

I have tried many things in my portfoliolist.js, such as:
1. Changing image: to image: "../img/barber-clube85.png"
2. passing the {barberclube} as a string

And i dont know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CRA? You can pass the image path directly in portfolio.image

Comment: yes i am. I tried passing in the PortfolioList.js array as image: "../img/barber-clube85.png" but it wont work.

Comment: Console.log your image in the component. With CRA, I get something like static/media path. One other minor thing, please dont use your index as key in your child. Use a uniqueId instead. Lodash offers you one if you have lodash in your project.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault. I was trying to import the image as

```
import {hero} from "../img/hero.svg";
```

But the right way is

```
import hero from "../img/hero.svg";
```

Sorry, i need some sleep.